# Forward already-running X-window-system applications through SSH

Tags: ssh, x11, headless, x11forwarding

I know that it is possible to forward the windows of an X-windows-system application to a client's desktop via SSH when you start the application in a SSH terminal session which has X-forwarding enabled.

But is there a way to forward the windows of an application which is already running on a remote system? Most impressive would be a way to keep a windowed application running on a headless server system, so that when I ever need that application I can forward its windows on-demand to my desktop system, without the need to ever stop this application or the application being closed down because my SSH connection times out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra). It's basically screen for X.

Answer (score 1):

[NX](http://nomachine.com/) is capable of keeping sessions alive.

Answer (score 1):

Vnc does this (on Linux the normal Vnc servers create a virtual display rather than sharing your desktop like in Windows), but you would need to have run the application in the Vnc server up front.

Comment: I know, but this way you have to forward a full desktop as far as I know. That's not what I'm looking for.